# accessing json response in kendo grid ui in Angular 7

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a json response from api service and the format as below , where I couldn't access them in front end `kendo-grid-column` , am trying to access the `amgName` and `SaleDays.Any` inputs will be helpful.

**sample data :**

```
enter code here {"data":[[{"amgId":12,"amgName":"Name","paramsLastUpdateUser":"testing data","paramsLastUpdateTime":"","paramsLastUpdateTimeTxt":"9/23/2019 10:25:14 AM","paramsUpdatedToday":false,"modelAllocationParameterId":3735,"cumulativeSpecialSalesSharePercent":100.0,"cumulativeSpecialSeasonalitySharePercent":100.0,"parameter":{"properties":{"SaleDays":90,"Year":3,"SalesShare%":0,"SeasonalityShare%":100,"SeasonalityOverride":"Car","MinDaysSupply%":0,"IncludeDemoQtyInTotalAvail":true,"SwapWidthLimit":200,"SwapDepthLimit":10,"ZoneSpecialPurpose%":5,"InclSeasonalityInDaysSupply":true,"HistoricalArrivalMonths":"3 - 2"}},"parameterLongDescription":{"properties":{"SaleDays":"Earnings Sale Days","Year":"Earnings Year","SalesShare%":"Earnings Sales Share %","SeasonalityShare%":"Earnings Seasonality Share %","SeasonalityOverride":"Override AMG Seasonality with other Models Seasonality","MinDaysSupply%":"Earnings Minimum Days Supply %","IncludeDemoQtyInTotalAvail":"Earnings Include Demo Qty in Total Avail","SwapWidthLimit":"Swap Width Limit","SwapDepthLimit":"Swap Depth Limit","ZoneSpecialPurpose%":"Zone Special Purpose %","InclSeasonalityInDaysSupply":"Include Seasonality In Days Supply","HistoricalArrivalMonths":"Earnings Historical Arrival Months"}}
```

Comment: I am confused.  Isn't the grid's data exposed by your service that gets it?

Comment: Yes , the grid-column doesn't fetch collection inside collection like so '[[' so to ignore the first empty collection i added a dummy variable and then was able to access the rest , the problem is with the collection style of the data , as of now i have made the service to return the collection like so {"data":[dummy string],[{"amgId":12,..}].and able to access as parameter.properties.SaleDays value.   let me know if there is better way to handle this in kendo grid column .Note :am adding multiple collection in a list and then sending it as response to UI.